# Variable defined w/ blank in {} can't work

Tags: linux, shell, csh

I have a file A.f which contain only one line of

```
Check something: {nameA nameB nameC}
```

then, I define a variable named var_A like

```
set var_A = `grep "Check something" A.f | head -n 1`
```

but this set failed with error msg of

```
Missing }.
```

It quite confuse me, so I have a test of:

```
echo {0}.    # 0
echo {0 1}.  # Missing }.
echo {0 }.   # Missing }.
echo "{0 1}" # {0,1}
```

which confuse me more, but I can find any meaning of {} in cshell is just about {} as a shorthand in list form.

Does anyone know why {} cant contain any blank?

Comment: While very old / classic texts, [csh programming considered harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) and [top 10 reasons not to use the csh shell](https://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt) are surprisingly relevant here, insofar as they go into the ad-hoc parser (and lack of a well-defined, strictly-implemented language spec) as the underlying source of why csh in particular is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know why {} cant contain any blank?

See the man page section [Filename substitution](https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/csh.1.html#lbAR):

> If a word contains … `{' …, then that word is a candidate for filename substitution…

Note that an unquoted word can't *contain any blank*.
We can't expect to be able to use special characters unquoted, so let's quote them:

```
set var_A = "`grep Check\ something A.f | head -n 1`"
```